# yeoman create node_modules for new webapp

Tags: yeoman

I new to yeoman and their new version which is grunt and bower, my question is, when I create new webapp running

```
yo webapp
```

under my project folder, the command after asking me some question regarding the inclusion of stuff like bootstrap, it creates a folder called node_modules, with a lor of files, is this normal??, don't this modules should be installed in a more global folder? thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js dependencies are [local to the project](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/). Hence the `node_modules` folder.